# Place Wordpress "Site Title" function within "Theme Options" page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

I've created a "*theme-options.php*" page within Wordpress, that can be found under the WP API "*Appearance*" settings menu.  On **this** page I would like to include two things **from** the *Settings* > *General-Options* page (the *Site Title* and *Tagline/Subheading*) that can be edited here (on my *Theme Options* page) and saved..

How do I go about achieving this?  I have this so far, which displays the boxes and information needed, but does not save/update properly.  What is it that I am missing?

**theme-options.php** :

```
// Build our Page
function build_options_page() {

// Page Structure
   ob_start(); ?>
     <div class="wrap">
       <?php screen_icon();?>
       <h2>Theme Options</h2>

       <p><b><label for="blogname"><?php _e('Site Title') ?></label></b></p>
       <p><input name="blogname" type="text" id="blogname" value="<?php form_option('blogname'); ?>" class="regular-text" />  
       <span class="description"><?php _e('The name of your site.') ?></span></p> 
       <br />

       <p><b><label for="blogdescription"><?php _e('Tagline or Subheading') ?></label></b></p>
       <p><input name="blogdescription" type="text" id="blogdescription"  value="<?php form_option('blogdescription'); ?>" class="regular-text" /> 
       <span class="description"><?php _e('A brief description of your site.') ?></span></p> 
       <p class="submit">
       <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
       </p>

     </div>
   <?php
   echo ob_get_clean();
   ?>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses the Profile page to display and modify the `blogname` and `blogdescription`, but should be pretty straight forward to port into your code.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 1 );

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
    ?>
    <table class="form-table">  
        <tr>
            <th><label for="user_address">Site Title</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="blogname" id="blogname" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('blogname') ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="user_zip">Tagline</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="blogdescription" id="blogdescription" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'blogdescription' ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
    <?php 
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_option( 'blogname', $_POST['blogname'] );
    update_option( 'blogdescription', $_POST['blogdescription'] );
}
```

Comment: I've taken what you've suggested and modified the original code a tad to conform to what I was after.  Thank you heaps!

Comment: @Rob : Maybe you could post your working code as an answer, so we have the proper solution documented here... & glad I could help :)